# Inserting data into an associative array in foreach

Tags: php

So I have this array `$companies`, which looks like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'id' => '54',
            'name' => 'Company 1',
            'phone' => '867038198',
            'start_date' => '2014-04-11'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'id' => '55',
            'name' => 'Company 2',
            'phone' => '867038199',
            'start_date' => '2014-04-23'
        )
    ))
```

then I have the following foreach loop:

```
foreach($companies as $company){

    $count = 3;
    $company['Company']['count'] = $count;
}
```

As I try to debug a `$company` inside the foreach, it is all good and the count is stored. But when I return the whole array of `$companies`, the `count` is not stored.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Its because you created a new array `$company`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foreach` works on a copy of the array. You can use a reference instead:

```
foreach($companies as &$company) {
    $count = 3;
    $company['Company']['count'] = $count;
}
unset($company); // clear the reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach works on a copy of the array. You can use a regular for loop instead:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($companies); $i++){

    $count = 3;
    $companies[$i]['Company']['count'] = $count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one is faster.

```
foreach($companies as $key=>$company) {
    $count = 3;
    $companies[$key]['Company']['count'] = $count;
}
```

Comment: "is faster" [citation needed]

Comment: How this will faster?